# Saving unwanted files in Hosting Space

Tags: hosting

I have a website providing me with 200GB of hosting space. All the files are under `/public_html/` folder and I only use 1-2MB of it.
So, I've saved many useful files [like my pictures, videos comprising of approx. 15GB; so that I never loose them. The files are also kept under `/public_html` and I've made it private.]. I just wanted to ask that whether this will affect the loading time or bandwidth of my website in any way. I think it won't; but still I wanted to ask it here on SO as I'm greatly confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I'd not save any sensitive/private stuff on my shared web hosting server. Its not very uncommon for hosting servers to be compromised. Therefore, you'd not want to store any private files in there.
- If you really want to use your hosting space as a backup space, don't store them in `/public_html`. Anything in there is ideally addressable via a URL. I am not sure how you've made it private though. Consider putting it one level up (in a new folder outside `/public_html`). This way they are out of document root and are not accessible via a URL.
- Now to answer your question - No, it will not affect the loading time and/or bandwidth of your website.

Comment: Most shared hosting providers give not assurances to the security of content stored in your hosting space.  Indeed most emphasise that it is the users responsibility to do disaster-recovery backup -- so yes, it doesn't impact your web app performance.  Yes, it's a sensible precaution to encrypt it since you don't know if access will be compromised, and no don't depend on it being their when you need it.